# How to reformat named.conf's zone blocks into single lines?

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, bind, tr

For reasons I won't go into here, I need to make a copy of an old CentOS 5.10 server's named.conf file and perform some text manipulation on the copy. The final result should consolidate each zone's info into a single, separate line. Plus, I need to script it so it can be run as a cron job. Here's an example of what I'm starting with:

```
zone "." {
        type hint;
        file "named.root";
};

zone "somedomain.com" {
        type master;
        file "somedomain.net";
        allow-transfer {
                11.11.11.11;
                22.22.22.22;
                common-allow-transfer;
        };
};

zone "otherdomain.com" {
        type master;
        file "otherdomain.com";
        allow-transfer {
                33.33.33.33;
                44.44.44.44;
                55.55.55.55;
                common-allow-transfer;
        };
};
```

And here's an example of what should appear in the edited file:

```
zone "." { type hint; file "named.root"; };
zone "somedomain.com" { type master; file "somedomain.net"; allow-transfer { 11.11.11.11; 22.22.22.22; common-allow-transfer; }; };
zone "otherdomain.com" { type master; file "otherdomain.com"; allow-transfer { 33.33.33.33; 44.44.44.44; 55.55.55.55; common-allow-transfer; }; };
```

My CIO and I unsuccessfully searched for existing scripts that convert named.conf into one-line-per-zone format. Using tr and sed, I've managed to 1) turn all tabs into spaces and 2) compress multiple contiguous spaces into a single space. The result is closer to what I need, but I'm still having trouble deleting unwanted newlines while keeping desired newlines. Here's example output which is close to being correct:

```
zone "." {
 type hint;
 file "named.root"; 
};
zone "somedomain.com" {
 type master;
 file "somedomain.net";
 allow-transfer {
 11.11.11.11;
 22.22.22.22;
 common-allow-transfer;
 };
};
zone "otherdomain.com" {
 type master;
 file "otherdomain.com";
 allow-transfer {
 33.33.33.33;
 44.44.44.44;
 55.55.55.55;
 common-allow-transfer;
 };
};
```

Tested a few suggested sed, awk, and tr expressions to solve the newline problem, but none of the expressions gave the desired output. Any suggestions you have--even a general direction like "experiment with sed and x,y,z"--would be very appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open up the file in Vim (or just `vi`) and type:

```
:g/^zone/.,/^}/j
```

Voila, you're done.

---

This runs `g`lobally, on every line beginning with `zone`, the command:

```
.,/^}/j
```

Which means, from the current line (`.`) to the next line that starts with a closing brace, `j`oin all those lines together.

---

If you need to script it, use `vi`'s scripted form, `ex`:

```
printf '%s\n' 'g/^zone/.,/^}/j' x | ex file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sed -n '
    /^zone/,/^};/ H          # append current line to hold space in this range
    /^};/ {                  # at the end of the range:
        s/.*//               #   erase the current line
        x                    #   exchange pattern space with hold space
        s/\n//               #   remove first newline (before "zone")
        s/[[:space:]]\+/ /g  #   condense all other whitespace including newlines
        p                    #   and print this zone record
    }
' named.conf
```

result

```
zone "." { type hint; file "named.root"; };
zone "somedomain.com" { type master; file "somedomain.net"; allow-transfer { 11.11.11.11; 22.22.22.22; common-allow-transfer; }; };
zone "otherdomain.com" { type master; file "otherdomain.com"; allow-transfer { 33.33.33.33; 44.44.44.44; 55.55.55.55; common-allow-transfer; }; };
```

Comment: Check the sed documentation ([the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/index.html), or `info sed`) for the commands I used.

Answer (score 0):

`sed -e ':nextline' -e N -e 's/\n\s*\([^z]\)/\1/' -e 'tnextline' named.conf`

Comment: Thank you! This almost got me there. Just have to tweak a little. Your help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using  the `paragraph-mode` of `awk` and `Perl` tools and the range operator `,` of the `sed` tool:

```
sed -e '
    /^zone/,/^$/!d
    H;/^zone/h;/^$/!{$!d;}
    g;s/[[:space:]]\{1,\}/ /g
    s/ $//
' input.file

awk -vRS= '{$1=$1}1' input.file

perl -pl -00e 's/\s+/ /g' input.file

perl -pl -00e 'tr/\t\040\n/ /s' input.file
```

**Output:**

```
zone "." { type hint; file "named.root"; };
zone "somedomain.com" { type master; file "somedomain.net"; allow-transfer { 11.11.11.11; 22.22.22.22; common-allow-transfer; }; };
zone "otherdomain.com" { type master; file "otherdomain.com"; allow-transfer { 33.33.33.33; 44.44.44.44; 55.55.55.55; common-allow-transfer; }; };
```